# Delete script using reserved Keywords in Column names fails in Liquibase

Tags: h2, liquibase

I want to delete some rows in the table "GRANTS". This table has column names "group", "grant" which are SQL reserved keywords. So, I tried to create a liquibase delete script with backquotes around column names. But still getting error.
This is my liquibase script.

```
  <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onFailMessage="Removal failed">
    <columnExists tableName="grants" columnName="group"/>
    <columnExists tableName="grants" columnName="grant"/>
  </preConditions>
    <delete tableName="grants">
        <where>`group`='Operator' AND `grant`='READ';</where>
    </delete>
</changeSet>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
DELETE FROM PUBLIC.grants WHERE `group`='GIPvalueServiceOperator' AND `grant`='REPORT'; [42122-222] [Failed SQL: (42122) DELETE FROM PUBLIC.grants WHERE `group`='GIPvalueServiceOperator' AND `grant`='REPORT';]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException:
Column "GROUP" not found; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM PUBLIC.grants WHERE `group`='GIPvalueServiceOperator' AND `grant`='REPORT'; [42122-222]
```

H2 version = 2.2.222,
Liquibase-Core version = 4.23.1

Looked through many questions but didn't find a working solution.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why you use MySQL-style quoted names of these columns in H2? These non-standard and non-portable identifiers in H2 are converted to upper case (with default settings) just like regular unquoted identifiers.

You need to quote them with standard double quotes like `"group"` and `"grant"` if they were defined in lower case.

To use `"` in XML you need to write it as `&quot;` (`&quot;group&quot;` etc.) or you can use `<!CDATA[ ]]>` section.